# Reading integers from standard input and inputting values into a vector

Tags: c++, vector

I want to read just the first line of standard input, and place the the values into a vector (unknown number of entries). With each vector element holding a value (i.e. `vector[1]=1`, `vector[2]=-30`...)

E.g.

```
1 -30 10 300
```

I've tried just using a while loop and `cin`, but I can't seem to make it stop at the terminating character `/n`. And I've been trying to implement this with `getline`, but I'm having no luck. Is there a good method to store integers from standard input, into a vector?

Any help is appreciated,
Thank you in advance. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The below code works fine for your problem. the answer from Mohit should use getline not readline

```
    vector <int> vec;
string input;
getline(cin,input);
istringstream ss(input);
int num;
while (ss >> num)
{
    vec.push_back(num);
}
vector<int>::iterator itr = vec.begin();
while (itr != vec.end())
{
    cout << *itr << endl;
    itr++;
}
```

The snippet prints back to the standard output.

Answer (score 1):

```
std::string line;
if( std::getline(std::cin, line) ) {
  std::istringstream ss(line);
  int i;
  while(ss >> i) {
    vec.push_back(i);
  }
}
```

As an alternative you can also use [istream iterators](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/istream_iterator) on `ss`.

Comment: Did you mean `istream_iterator`?